# Is there a name for the three step backwards compatibility software release?

Tags: language-agnostic, release-management

The release method I am talking about is this:

1. Release code that works with both old and new clients (forwards and backwards compatible)
2. Release client that only works with the new code released in step 1
3. Release code that removes the backwards compatibility that was supported in step 1

Example:

1. Add new stored procedure that has modified signature
2. Add new code that uses new stored procedure
3. Remove old stored procedure

On a larger scale this could also refer to deprecating versions of internal APIs.

Is there a general name for this chain of releases? If not can we coin a term for this so I can stop calling it "That 3-step release thing that we need to do"

Comment: I hereby dub this the transient compatibility pattern.

Comment: I think that "transition" is a relevant word, though less specific than you want.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I used "Transient Compatibilty Pattern" in a conversation yesterday and no one batted an eye. It is now a thing.

Comment: @TheHonorableSamuelClemens so long as they understood what you meant. Otherwise God help us all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is a deliberate and announce shift to a new API this is called "good practice", "phased implementation", "transitory introduction" or "backwards compatibility" - if the process also introduces a warning when the transitory items are used, (also a good practice), it is called [Deprecation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation).

It is also worth reading up on [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) - *unfortunately both the practice you are asking about and Semantic Versioning are more common in the open source world than in many commercial organisations.*